# Storing ArrayBuffer in mongodb with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, axios, mern

I am trying to store the book's array buffer in MongoDB with the help of mongoose. I am getting some error related to validation I hope you guys can help me.

Here is my back-end:

This is my schema

```
...
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    book: {
        type: Buffer,
    },
});
...
```

router:

```
...
router.post("/api/book", auth, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { user } = req;
        user.book = req.body.book;
        await user.save();
        res.send({ success: true });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.name, error.message);
        res.send({ success: false, error });
    }
});
...
```

Here is my front-end:

This is the place where I did a post request

```
...
getBook = async (book) => {
        console.log(book);
        if (book) {
            try {
                const res = await axios.post(
                    "/api/book",
                    { book },
                    {
                        headers: {
                            Authorization:
                                "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjVlYTJlOWJlZmI0OTVhMDZhZTkzZjZmNyIsImlhdCI6MTU4NzczNDk3NH0.fzoJcHbkVhkgYZZgYP0N1XNdqf6uowAVrekntuulOu0",
                        },
                    }
                );
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error.name, error.message);
            }
        }

...
```

this is the place where o get the book and converted it into array buffer and passed it to above code

```
...
handleOnChange = (event) => {
        if (event.target.files[0].type === "application/epub+zip") {
            let reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(event.target.files[0]);

            reader.onload = () => {
                this.props.getBook(reader.result);
            };
        } else {
            alert("Only .epub Files are supported");
        }
    };
...
```

and here is my error at server side

```
ValidationError User validation failed: book: Cast to Buffer failed for value "{}" at path "book"
POST /api/book 200 198.131 ms - 533
```

I think it is because I am using the wrong data type in the mongoose schema

Comment: Did you find any answer to this?